# Reprocess results got from server

Tags: php, python, webforms, flask

I am making a webpage which, largely, aims to submit a form to another webpage, process the results further, and display them on browser.

[1] Input form is ready. The form data is to be submitted to http://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/hhpred/

[2] After the form is submitted, my webpage is redirected to the "Waiting" page of that website.

How do I stop this redirect? I cannot use AJAX, because it cannot work between different domains. (**Can I ?**)

Further, I need to get the response data and process it.

A possible solution can be: a PHP script, which should work as:

form-->submitted to my server-->submitted from my server to http: //toolkit ... -->response received by server --> processed further -->diplayed on browser

Currently I have created the webpage with flask. I have also used flask for "process further part".

**My Question is: How can this process be acheived?**

**If I use PHP, how to integrate it with Flask?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ which supports crossdomain requests...at least in a way